# Paginação manual no Spring Boot com Criteria

Tags: java, spring-boot, criteria

Olá, estou dando manutenção em um código que deveria fazer uma paginação usando criteria porem nos parametros do método informa que pageable nunca foi usado e não sei como implementar ele.

```
public List<Order> findOrderByFilter(OrderQueryDTO filter, int page, int size, Pageable pageable) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Order> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Order.class);

    Root<Order> root = criteriaQuery.from(Order.class);
    List<Predicate> p = new ArrayList<>();
```

O resto abaixo são vários predicados para fazer vários filtros com if e elses no final o retorno está como:

```
TypedQuery<Order> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return query.getResultList();
```

Conseguem me ajudar a implementar esse pageable nesse metodo?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar onde a *query* começa e termina com base na `Pageable`.

```java
query.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
```

Link: [JPA Pagination - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination)